# QML TableView rowDelegate styleData.row not defined

Tags: qt, qml, tableview

I am trying to create a custom row delegate for a `TableView`. according to the [Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#rowDelegate-prop), the `rowDelegate` should have access to a property called `styleData.row`. However, when I'm try to access this property, it is undefined. I used the debugger to check whats inside the `styleData`, and the `row` is missing:

[image: QML debugger - value of <code>styleData</code>]

My code is very simple:

```
TableView {
    width: 500//DEBUG
    height: 300//DEBUG

    model: ListModel {
        ListElement {
            lectureName: "Baum1"
        }
        ListElement {
            lectureName: "Baum2"
        }
        ListElement {
            lectureName: "Baum3"
        }
        ListElement {
            lectureName: "Baum4"
        }
    }

    rowDelegate: HeaderRowDelegate {//simply a Rectangle with an in property called "modelRow"
        id: rowDelegate
        modelRow: {
            var data = styleData;
            return data.row;
        }
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        id: c1
        role: "lectureName"
        title: "TEST"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try a simple `modelRow: styleData.row`?

Comment: Yes, that was the way I tried it first. That failed the, so I created the "function" to use the debugger

Comment: How do you check/note (without using debugger) that the value is `undefined`?

Comment: The console. I it shows the error "cannot assing [undefined] to integer". And if I check the contents it's always invalid

Comment: What do you want to do with this property in `HeaderRowDelegate`? Please show some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to assign it yourself: as the `HeaderRowDelegate` component is assigned to the `rowDelegate` property of the `TableView`, your component has already access to the `styleData.row` property.

Here's an example:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: app
    title: qsTr("Test")
    width: 800
    height: 600

    TableView {
        width: 500//DEBUG
        height: 300//DEBUG

        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                lectureName: "Baum1"
            }
            ListElement {
                lectureName: "Baum2"
            }
            ListElement {
                lectureName: "Baum3"
            }
            ListElement {
                lectureName: "Baum4"
            }
        }

        rowDelegate: RowDel {}        

        TableViewColumn {
            id: c1
            role: "lectureName"
            title: "TEST"
        }
    }
}
```

Now the row delegate, **RowDel.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Rectangle {
    id: rowDel
    color: "blue"
    height: 60

    readonly property int modelRow: styleData.row ? styleData.row : 0

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log("[!] log: " + modelRow);
        }
    }       
}
```

The important thing here is that you can reference `styleData.row` directly from your component (obliviously as long as you use this precise component as a row delegate).

As an example, if you click on each tableview row, you should see the correct row number displayed in the console log:

```
qml: [!] log: 0
qml: [!] log: 1
qml: [!] log: 2
qml: [!] log: 3
```

Comment: If I try the exact same files you posted, I still get the following result:
`qrc:/RowDel.qml:8:37: Unable to assign [undefined] to int`

Comment: @Felix : updated **RowDel.qml** with `modelRow: styleData.row ? styleData.row : 0` to check if row exists or not. That might do the trick (at least it works with `qmlscene`). Tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Seems the property changes later to the real value.