# How to hide unused rows in a TableView in QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Below code shows unused rows in the table. I want the unused rows to disappear. A white space should be shown instead.

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    TableView
    {
        height: 300; width: 300
        TableViewColumn {
                role: "title"
                title: "Title"
                width: 100
            }
            TableViewColumn {
                role: "author"
                title: "Author"
                width: 200
            }
            model: libraryModel
    }

    ListModel {
        id: libraryModel
        ListElement {
            title: "A Masterpiece"
            author: "Gabriel"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Brilliance"
            author: "Jens"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
    }
}
```

What are my options?

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958231/qml-tableview-rowdelegate-styledata-row-not-defined). What you need to do is to create your own delegate so it will just be white color if there is no data in it.

Comment: @MaximSkvortsov Thanks for pointing that out. It helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line has to be added in the `rowDelegate` of the TableView:

`readonly property int modelRow: styleData.row ? styleData.row : 0`

```
        rowDelegate: Rectangle 
                     {
                        id: rowDel
                        border.width: 1
                        height:  52
                        width: 2000

                        readonly property int modelRow: styleData.row ? styleData.row : 0
                     }
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33972305/462608